# Modifying Dart pub-cache folders Flutter SDK

Tags: flutter, dart, sdk, tensorflow-lite

I am following [these instructions](https://pub.dev/packages/tflite_flutter#ios) to add tensorflow lite to my flutter project. I am directed to add a folder to `~/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/tflite_flutter-<plugin-version>/ios/`. However, it does not exist.

I noticed in `~/.pub-cache/hosted/` another directory named `pub.dev/`. The path `tflite_flutter-<plugin-version>/ios/` does exist in here.

[image]

What is the difference between these two subdirectories?

Am I safe to assume I can add the folder in `~/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/tflite_flutter-<plugin-version>/ios/` instead?

Comment: I read [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/FlutterDev/comments/blfkgi/since_when_did_pubdartlangorg_change_to_pubdev/) that there was a website name change, but this was 4 years ago, my project directory is only 3 months old, and the tflite package is under 2 years old. I cannot imagine this is due to a deprecation, but am curious to know what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package versions published before a certain date will be found under `pub.dartlang.org`, with newer versions being placed under `pub.dev`. As long as you add the folder in the package directory matching the `<plugin-version>` you're using, things should work as expected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This answer enabled code that works as expected!